# Is there a way to return a default value in a function without a return statement?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

For example:

```
private bool isThisADumbQuestion(bool trustMeThisWilLBeTrue)
{
    if (trustMeThisWilLBeTrue)
        return true;
}
```

This always gives the error that not all paths return a value. Is it possible in the function declaration to have it a return a default value in this case? Logically speaking:

```
private (bool = false) isThisADumbQuestion() {}
```

I'm guessing it's not possible, but I'm still learning a lot of C# syntax so I thought I'd ask just in case. Seems like it'd be a useful bit of functionality to potentially save a lot of checking within the function body.

**EDIT:**
The above code is a logical example and not to be taken as an actual method. I edited it so that it will actually give the error promised. Sorry for the trouble, folks.

Comment: I don't think your initial code snippet compiles with the error you describe. The compiler is smart enough to know that `if (true)` will always be executed, and so it will not complain, since it knows that the method *will* always return a value. If you switch the code to `bool myVar = true; if (myVar) return true;` *then* you'll get an error.

Comment: Yes, this is a silly question. Come up with a better exampe and we will explain the reason your logic is wrong. Your current example is silly.  I was going to try to explain it but I cannot stand my answer because of the nature of the question

Comment: The code wasn't meant to be compiled. I don't actually have any methods called isThisADumbQuestion() - it'd return true waaaaaay too often. =) This was more a logical example as "code", so I don't know if the compiler would actually puke or not on that.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure why you would say that. This is a feature that I personally had not considered, but I can certainly see its utility. Further, the OP mentioned that he thought not, but he was learning, and figured it would be worth asking. Sure, he could have gone through the C# language spec to find the answer, but if everyone did that, SO would lose a *lot* of questions.

Comment: @Yatrix Fair enough. In general, if you're going to make an assertion about some code, it should probably be true :)

Comment: @Ramhound how high that horse you're sitting on, sir? Jeesh. Coding and conversations CAN be a little fun without the world coming to an end. Luckily, the other 9 people didn't struggle to understand my example.

Comment: @dlev Since it was a syntax question, I didn't really expect anyone to compile the code as I wasn't asking for help with the logic itself. Fair enough criticism, though. Thanks anyway, dude.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No this is not possible.  All code paths on a non-void returning function must terminate with an explicit `return` or `throw` statement.

Note: As xanatos pointed out there is an exception to the above rule for methods which the C# compiler can determine never terminate.  For example

```
int Test() {
  while (true) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **no**.

A method with a non-void return value must **always** `return` a value. An "exceptional" case is when an exception is thrown with `throw`.

But I guess you could solve it by creating a variable at the top of your method and initialize it with a default value.

```
bool SomeMethod()
{
    bool retVal = true;

    if (someFlagHasBeenSet)
        retVal = false;

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Yah, I thought about that but that's cheating. =)

Comment: @Yatrix - Cheating huh? Explain yourself.

Comment: I was just teasing. That's a workaround for what I was trying to workaround. A man could get lost in all that working around. Thanks, though. Appreciate the contribution.

Answer (score 2):

No, default return values aren't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a return statement at the very end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

> This always gives the error that not all paths return a value.

No, it does not. The compiler is smart enough to detect, in this particular case, the end of the method body is not reachable.

> Is it possible in the function declaration to have it a return a default value in this case?

No, it is not. In fact, the end of a non-void method must not be reachable.

> Seems like it'd be a useful bit of functionality to potentially save a lot of checking within the function body.

It's no easier than just putting

```
return false;
```

at the very bottom of your method before the closing brace for the method body. However, for a language designer and compiler writer, given that what you are proposing is already in a certain sense possible within the language as currently designed, there is no value in adding the feature that you propose but a very significant cost to do so.

Comment: "All code paths for a function with return type that is not void must throw or return." Not necessarily. Consider `int Blah() { while (true) Console.WriteLine("Do I compile?"); }` At least in 4.0, the compiler is smart enough to detect the inf-loop. I would put it as "The end of a non-void method must not be reachable." If the compiler can prove that this is the case, there's no issue.

Comment: Code was meant to illustrate what I meant, not to be actually taken literally and compiled. Sry.

Comment: @Yatrix: You're dealing with programmers on a Q&A forum. Say what you mean, literally. Don't give a block of a code and then make a false assertion about it, and then claim it wasn't to be taken literally. Code is always meant to be taken literally, that's what compilers do with it.

Comment: @Jason Something about your post twigged that I had read this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/24/never-say-never-part-two.aspx

Comment: @Jason I'll roll with pseudo-code next time for clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just have one return statement at the end and a variable that is being changed throughout the entire function. The default return is what you initially set it to.

Comment: Yah, but that defeats the purpose of my question, as I'd still be having to write a statement for each condition setting it to true or false. I was looking at checking for all trues and if none worked out then it would just return false. Thanks, though.

Comment: That's a common-ish thing in .NET languages. In Java not so much.

Comment: I'm a 5year VB programmer in my 5th month of C#. I've found some neat syntax things in C# that I couldn't do in VB, so I thought I'd ask. No previous C experience, save for college and you know how "complex" that gets.

Comment: Very much so. Just out my college myself last year.

Comment: They did teach me how to write cout and cin statements, so good that was real cool.

Comment: I learned to copy and paste what my teacher did. That was fun.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4241/discussion-between-camelslack-and-yatrix)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can structure your function like this:

```
private bool myFunc() {

    bool retval = false;

    if(some condition) {
        doSomething();
        retval = true;
    } else if(some other condition) {
        retval = true;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible to do what you're saying you could solve it like this?

```
 private bool isThisADumbQuestion()
 {
      if(true)
         return true;
      return false;
 }
```

Then it returns false (by default sorta)

Answer (score 0):

Only way with out returning from a method is by throwing an exception this way

```
 public static int Method()
        {
            if (true)
                throw new Exception();

        }
```

@OP, i am just showing you that you can bypass that error by not returning any value or by using return statement. Just for your information. So please don't use this in your production code.

Comment: Why on earth would you suggest that?  Jason's answer is the best to be honest.  In other words this question is silly considering his example will already compile.

Comment: Well its not suggestion but an answer that you can fool compiler error w.r.t returning value thingy. I did not wanted the OP to go back convincing himself that no way else exists. Its just for his FYI.